# Light switch won’t turn off light

Tags: switch, light

Please help

I have recently changed a light fitting which I have done a hundred times before but this time the switch won’t turn off.

The cables from the ceiling are twin and earth, the light fitting is double insulated so no need for the Earth cable so we just take this off.
We have a loop the two red wires in a connector and placed the other red live wire into the live connection to black wires into the neutral connection and the switch wire, which is a black wire with a red sleeve into the other live position, there is power going to the light, but the switch does not turn it off so it is on permanently

[image]

---

We did remove the rose before taking a photo, but have this photo of another light in the house.

[image]

Ruskes are you saying to remove the red wire from the N position?

The earth cables have just been taped up, we haven’t done anything else with them.

Can you tell me what what you think I need to do with the wires to correct

Comment: I think you have a switch loop.  With a switch loop power from the ceiling is connected to (in NA) to the switch cable neutral(N) and only the switch live is connected to the light.  You need to find/know the ceiling power wires and the switch wires

Comment: Did you remove a ceiling rose with your last light? Did you photograph it first? If that's a switch loop with the power in the ceiling [which is what it looks like] you need 3 sets of bus bars, in, loop, out.  You've shorted the switch loop [black with red sheath & one other black] into the power. See 2nd image here - http://www.lightwiring.co.uk/multi-point-radial-lighting-circuit-old-cable-colours/ I'd also like to know for certain what you've done with those earths. if nothing else they should be bonded togather & to that metal hanger.

Comment: In addition to Ruskes' answer - you seem to have several taped up Earth wires.  Are they connected to each other?  If not, then they need to be connected to each other even if the light fitting is double insulated.

Answer (score 2):

You only need the `black wire with a red sleeve` which is switchable hot (on/off) you do not need the other one in the same spot so remove it.

If that does not work, move the now single on to the top in the connection there to restore the switch loop.

Comment: Yeah, the 'spare' red needs to go into the terminal block - but overall, this 'accidentally getting it nearly right' tells me an electrician is needed next time, not DIY guesswork. Floating earths show complete disregard for safety & had the switch loop not been red-sheathed… ...

Comment: Wow, I was looking for advice not a lecture

Comment: @SadieCriscuolo I agree with you so I gave you advice not a lecture

Comment: The lecture comes free with every death-trap wiring scheme.

Comment: Thanks all, thanks Ruskes, it is now all working..and I have grouped the earths together to avoid death Tetsujin. Thank you